# You are running 5.6.30. in C:\phpServer\Laravel\Project1\vendor\composer\platform_check.php on line 25

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm new on Laravel, I already installed PHP and I have used it in a local server with EasyPHP. I also installed Composer, here might be a problem thus I first installed it in a default folder where the PHP was lower than v8. Then I re-installed Composer in the right folder with the version 8.2.8.
I created a new proyect with Laravel using the command: composer create-project laravel/laravel Project1
Everything seemed to be ok, thus I didn't see an error. However, once I access to my local server and I open the file: http://127.0.0.1:8080/edsa-Laravel/Project1/public/, I have the following message:

> Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer
> dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0". You are running 5.6.30.
> in C:\phpServer\Laravel\Project1\vendor\composer\platform_check.php on
> line 25

I have nothing on the line 25. This is the contect of the file only a ;

Why composer says that Im using the PHP lower than 8.1, while I have 8.2 and the last time I installed Composer, I did it in the new folder? How can I fix this?

I already uninstalled composer in the Windows Control Panel, and re-installed it again.
I already restart my PC.
I open the file mentioned on the browser, and I don't see something about the PHP version.
I checked some helps on stackoverflow, and they suggest to add the following code in a composer.json file:

```
{
    "config": {
        "platform-check": false
    }
}
```

I added this line in the project composer.json file, and it still shows the error.
Also I tried the commmand: composer global update. I tried this command in the Project1 folder (same where the composer.json file is located), and it shows the following:

```
Changed current directory to C:/Users/User1/AppData/Roaming/Composer
Composer could not find a composer.json file in C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\Composer
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file. See https://getcomposer.org/basic-usage
```

Comment: Did you check the PHP version installed in EasyPHP?

Comment: Are there multiple instances of PHP running in your computer? If not, run in your terminal `php -v` to check.

Comment: How is this problem related to Laravel or Composer itself? Using PHP 5.6.30 sounds like a horrible idea, as this is out of support since years